# Any other option to run oozie actions in parallel

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

Currently I have 6 actions in my oozie workflow as shown below.

After MainJob1 completes all the first, second and third jobs should run in parallel.
After MainJob2 completes only second and third jobs should run in parallel.

Is there any possibility to solve the above way of workflow executions?

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
  ....
<decision name="execution-mode-decision">
    <switch>
        <case to="MainJob1">${executionMode eq "DEFAULT"}</case>
        <case to="MainJob2">${executionMode eq "INVALID"}</case>
        <default to="MainJob1" />
    </switch>
    </decision>
    <action name="MainJob1">
        <map-reduce>
            .......
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="fork1"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>

    <action name="MainJob2">
        <map-reduce>
           ......
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="fork2"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    ...
    <fork name="fork1">
        <path start="firstparalleljob"/>
        <path start="secondparalleljob"/>
        <path start="thirdparalleljob"/>
    </fork>

   <fork name="fork2">
        <path start="secondparalleljob"/>
        <path start="thirdparalleljob"/>
    </fork>
    <action name="firstparallejob">
        <map-reduce>
         ...........
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="secondparalleljob">
        <map-reduce>
           ........
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="thirdparalleljob">
        <map-reduce>
           ........
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <join name="joining" to="emailFailure"/>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put firstparalleljob, secondparalleljob and thirdparalleljob in separate 3 sub-workflows, then call 3 sub workflows in the first fork and 2 sub-workflow in next fork. In this way, we can even pass a different value to a variable at different fork time in the same action.

Comment: My pleasure :-)